# Why Duplicate SELECT Not Working for Database

Tags: php, database

I have a php script code to display the columns in the table topics, and also a column in the table users. But it does not work as I expected.

I compile the code like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, jenis FROM topics WHERE message LIKE '%" . $word . "%' ORDER BY message LIMIT 10, SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE users LIKE '%" . $word . "%' ORDER BY users LIMIT 10";
```

How should?

Comment: Because you have a comma separating the queries where you should have a semi-colon. Once you fix that you'll encounter other problems.

Comment: @Jay How should the code was compiled? I do not understand about the semi-colon

Comment: Queries must be separated by semi-colons. The semi-colon is the *end of statement* for SQL.

Comment: More importantly, why are you running two queries in one line, on php, while you could perhaps do a join? what's the relation between the two tables? Any common user_id, or something?

Comment: U can use mysqli_multi_query

Comment: They can @devpro, if they're using the MySQLi API. At this point we do not know what they're using.

Comment: I'm not sure the op needs a mysqli_multi_query (for his apparent level). Perhaps he wants to join the info from 2 tables?

Comment: Norax r u using mysqli? Or mysql? Or PDO ? or any framework? @jay-blanchard u r right sir

Comment: I think that @peixotorms is probably right here, but it would be hard to know without the OP answering some questions.

Comment: @peixotorms  I want to create a search engine for my site. For the result, I will present details of posts and author sender. So this using two different tables.
Maybe you have a better solution?

Comment: Resolved or still waiting?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you need to use [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) to execute multiple statements in one statement string. Also note that to separate two queries you need `;`instead of `,`

Comment: Why should the OP "use this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand this method